# How do I find the Sharpe Ratio?

Tags: sharpe-ratio, stochastic-discount

Suppose I'm given two assets, $x_0$, $x_1$ and the stochastic discount factor m. How do I find $m_p$, then use it to compute Sharpe($R_p$)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this a text-book thing?

Comment: Please use latex and explain the difference between $m$ and $m_p$ and if you have assets $x_0$ and $x_1$ (prices? returns?) how does $R_p$ relate to that?